# How to mock two axios call in same endpoint

Tags: node.js, mocking, jestjs, axios, ava

**Example:**

In my test I need to mock the two calls to the external apis.
I can't mock on the second call. With the library 'axios-mock-adapter' and ava I could only mock the first call.

```
const read = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const responseOne = await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://api.example.com/search/repositories',
      params: {
        q: 'example',
      },
    })
    const resultOne = responseOne.data
    if (resultOne) {
      let aux = []
      const itemsOne = resultOne.items.slice(0, 10)
      return Promise.all(
        itemsOne.map((p, indexOne) => {
          aux = [...aux, { id: p.id, name: p.name, arr: [] }]
          return axios({
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${SECRET_KEY}` },
            method: 'get',
            url: 'https://api.example2.com/search/things',
            params: { q: p.name },
          })
            .then(responseTwo =>
              responseTwo.data.array.map(i => {
                aux[indexOne].arr.push({
                  id: i.id,
                  created_at: i.created_at,
                  text: i.text,
                })
              })
            )
            .catch(err => res.status(500).json(err))
        })
      )
        .then(() => res.json({ result: aux }))
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json(err))
    } else res.status(404).json({ message: 'Example not found' })
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err)
  }
}
```

#### TEST

This is my test read.test.js.
Now I am dealing with the 'ava' and 'axios-mock-adapter' libraries. But the second axios call does not working the mock.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter'
import test from 'ava'
import read from '../read'

var mock = new MockAdapter(axios)


test('GET - /examples', async t => {
  mock
    .onGet('https://api.example.com/search/repositories, {
      params: {
        q: 'example',
      },
    })
    .reply(200, {
      total_count: 2,
      incomplete_results: false,
      items: [
        {
          id: 555,
          name: 'exampleOne',
        },
        {
          id: 666,
          name: 'exampleTwo',
        },
      ],
    })
    .onGet('https://api.example2.com/search/things', {
      params: { q: 'name' },
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${SECRET_KEY}` },
    })
    .reply(200, {
      statuses: [
        {
          id: 123,
          created_at: 'Thu Feb 27 22:54:02 +0000 2020',
          text: 'Example one.',
        },
        {
          id: 456,
          created_at: 'Wed Feb 26 13:40:20 +0000 2020',
          text: 'Example Two',
        },
      ],
    })

  try {
    const res = await read()
    t.assert(res.result[0].id.test(555))
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`ERROR::: ${err}`)
  }
```

Comment: Can you add to the question your current test code?

Comment: it was added. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the mock of the second request is that you are configuring it to respond only if the endpoint is requested with the params `{ q: 'name' }`. If you want to respond with the same data for all the requests to `https://api.example2.com/search/things` it is enough to remove that params atribute:

```
.onGet('https://api.example2.com/search/things', {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${SECRET_KEY}` },
})
.reply(200, {
    statuses: [
        {
            id: 123,
            created_at: 'Thu Feb 27 22:54:02 +0000 2020',
            text: 'Example one.',
        },
        {
            id: 456,
            created_at: 'Wed Feb 26 13:40:20 +0000 2020',
            text: 'Example Two',
        },
    ],
})
```

There are also other problems present in your test. In the mocked response you are passing the data in a property `statuses` but in your actual code you are iterating over an `array` property.

Also, the `read` method receives two parameters, `req` and `res`. If you don't provide those objects when calling `read` in your test it will break, as you are calling methods of the `res` object.

The simplest way to call the method would be by creating fake `req` and `res` objects and calling the `read` method with them. For the sake of simplicity, I will create the mock with the help of [sinon spies](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v9.0.0/spies/):

```
test('GET - /examples', async t => {
  mock
    .onGet('https://api.example.com/search/repositories, {
      params: {
        q: 'example',
      },
    })
    .reply(200, {
      total_count: 2,
      incomplete_results: false,
      items: [
        {
          id: 555,
          name: 'exampleOne',
        },
        {
          id: 666,
          name: 'exampleTwo',
        },
      ],
    })
    .onGet('https://api.example2.com/search/things', {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${SECRET_KEY}` },
    })
    .reply(200, {
      array: [
        {
          id: 123,
          created_at: 'Thu Feb 27 22:54:02 +0000 2020',
          text: 'Example one.',
        },
        {
          id: 456,
          created_at: 'Wed Feb 26 13:40:20 +0000 2020',
          text: 'Example Two',
        },
      ],
    })

  const res = {
    status: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
    json: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
  };

  try {
    await read({}, res);
    const data = res.json.firstCall.args[0];
    t.is(data.result[0].id, 555)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`ERROR::: ${err}`)
  }
});
```

Note that I'm mocking the request object by passing an empty object, since the `read` method does not use any property of the request.

Comment: How do I provide res and req in my test? Because "read" is the method called when the endpoint is called in my api

_**Example**_

`
const routesExamples = app => {
  app.get('/examples, read)
}
`

Comment: I have updated the answer to respond to your last question.

Comment: It worked, I ended up using 3 libraries: ava, sinon and axios-mock-adapter.  But I think I could just use ava with Sinon. But I don't know how to mock Sinon. Thank you very much!!!